# Identifying the appropriate model for determining the dimension with the most impact on poverty

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, quantiles, gamlss, ordered-probit

I am working on a research to determine the dimension (health, unemployment, education and standard of living) with the most impact on poverty. The response variable is the decile score obtained for each household in the National Social Register calculated using the Proxy Means Test(PMT).The decile score is between 1 - 10, decreasing score indicates severity of poverty.

1. Considering the seemingly ordered nature of the response variable, can ordinal Probit regression be employed for the study ?
2. For the purpose of comparison, am considering a distributional regression approach; GAMLSS or Quantile Regression but not certain of the suitability of the response variable

Further insight and clarity on the suitability or otherwise of the proposed models will be appreciated

Comment: "Impact," if not used with care, is likely to mislead non-statistical audiences into believing you are performing a causal analysis, but Probit regression doesn't do that (alone).  "Association" would be a more accurate term to use in its place.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me exactly what your response variable is.
All tYour response variable (decile score)
appears to be an integer value from 1 to 10.

How is this obtained from the Proxy Means Test?
Why is it a decile score?

Does decile 1 indicate any value between 0 and 1,

similarly does decile 2 indicate any value between 1 and 2?

In which case dividing the values by 10, gives values from 0.1 to 1, where 0.1 is really in the censored interval (0,0.1), etc.

You could treat the response as censored data and fit it using a "censored" distribution, e.g. a censored beta distribution.

Easier might be to subtract 1 from the response variable, to give values from 0 to 9,
and then fit a binomial or beta binomial distribution.

All the above distributions are available in gamlss.

Alternatively treat the response variable as an ordered categorical variable;
gamlss does not have this option.